# Two types of product categories on shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, widgets

I'm hoping someone can help me out with what i'm trying to do currently.

I'm using widgets to show the categories on my shop page, and I want to add two types of product categories in it. The first product category would show the paint type, if it is water based or solvent based. And the second category would show only lists of paint by surface, if it is for metal or for wood.

I've tried to find answers from google, but I can't seem to find what i'm looking for. I found that I can exclude some categories on my shop page, but it really won't do since I need to show two differnt categories and excluding will only help if I have one.

I wonder how can I do this? I'll attach a photo so hopefully someone can get what i'm trying to say.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to exclude the Uncategorized category from the loop or widget?

That would take some custom code to exclude it from that widget. Or you could probably set one of these categories as the default and just delete Uncategorized.

EDIT: You can call the WooCommerce Products into page content by category using shortcodes.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't myself sound too clear, English isn't my native language. 

Not really, I don't mind the uncategorized. But I want two make separate product categories for the shop page; one for Paint Type and for Surface Paint.

As of right now, I can only include one product category with all of the categories mixed together on the sidebar. I want to separate the two categories.